# 'automatic broadcasting operation applied' on equally sized matrices

Tags: octave

I'm writing a homework and I run into this error using Octave. It does not affect functionality of my solution, however I'm curious why this warning is being emitted.

```
% X is column vector, p is max degree of polynom
% example:
% X = [1;2;3;4], p = 3
% X_poly = [1,1,1; 2,4,8; 3,9,27; 4,16,64]
function [X_poly] = polyFeatures(X, p)

powers = ones(numel(X),1) * linspace(1,p,p);
X_poly = X .^ powers;

end
```

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the analysis with this:

```
powers = ones(numel(X),1) * linspace(1,p,p);
```

The left factor is obviously `numel(X)`-by-`1`, and the right factor is `1`-by-`p`, and you get a matrix that's `numel(X)`-by-`p`.

Then here's the problem:

```
X_poly = X .^ powers;
```

The left operand is `numel(X)`-by-`1` and the right operand is `numel(X)`-by-`p`.  These don't match.

I think it should simply be an error, but octave is apparently trying to figure out what you meant instead of what you wrote, but then giving you a warning that it is guessing.

To have singleton expansion performed, you can use `bsxfun` or `repmat`.

```
X_poly = bsxfun(@power, X, powers);
X_poly = repmat(X, 1, p) .^ powers;
```

Since the assignment to `powers` is just a messy way to do `repmat`, and `bsxfun` will expand both parameters, you can instead just do:

```
X_poly = bsxfun(@power, X, 1:p);
```

which makes it somewhat pointless to have a special function for this purpose.

[image]

Comment: Well I could have used bsxfun, but for the sake of exercise I wanted to implement this behavior myself.

Only thing needed to make my code work is to transform X also then.

powers = ones(numel(X),1) * linspace(1,p,p);
Xs = X * ones(1,p);
X_poly = Xs .^ powers;

Thank you very much ;)

Comment: "I think it should simply be an error, but octave is apparently trying to figure out what you meant instead of what you wrote, but then giving you a warning that it is guessing". That's not the reason. Part of Octave language is automatic broadcasting (inspired from NumPy), so what you write in those situations *is* broadcasting. The reason for the warning is that it's a new feature and may catch people by surprise. Those types of warnings are usually removed after 2 releases.

Comment: @carandraug: Well, the question is also tagged `matlab`, and it's illegal there.

Comment: I tagged it with matlab, because Octave is just freeware option to matlab and most of the code written for both of them can be interpreted by the other one.

Answer (score 12):

Automatic broadcasting is a fairly new Octave feature which throws in a bsxfun wherever there's a dimension mismatch between a singleton and non-singleton dimension.

In this case

X_poly = X .^ powers;

is replaced with

X_poly = bsxfun(@power, X, powers);

This is perfectly legal octave behavior and further it appears to be exactly what you want to do, so you don't *have* to change it at all.

The warning is because Matlab does not support automatic broadcasting so they want to remind you if you tried to run this code in Matlab it would fail.

Futhermore, common practice among many Octave programmers is to rely primarily on size mismatch as a way to detect bugs in their program.  I even once took a machine learning class where the prof said to the whole class "If all the dimensions line up, then it's probably correct".  This is terrible, terrible advice and a sure way to make sure everyone fails the homework assignments, but it does reflect a common approach among many researchers to writing Matlab/Octave programs.

For this reason, the introduction of automatic broadcasting without any warning could cause bug-tracing difficulties for you if you're not in the habit of making explicit assertions about your function inputs.

If you want to get rid of the warning, you can simply add

```
warning("off", "Octave:broadcast");
```

to your code.

If you want to maintain better Matlab compatibility or just don't use automatic broadcasting and would rather have octave error to help isolate bugs, you can add

```
warning ("error", "Octave:broadcast");
```

instead.